# How to add a delay to a JavaScript redirect and close?

Tags: javascript, window

Does anyone know how I can add a 5 second delay before this script redirects and closes the window?

```
<script>
    window.opener.location = '/redirect.html';
    window.close();
</script>
```

Comment: Note: there's no jQuery in that code, it's just plain JavaScript

Answer (score 5):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.opener.location = '/redirect.html';
    window.close();
}, 5000);
```

It works by passing in a function and a certain delay, in milliseconds. The function will be called after the delay expired.